# CSS percentage not correct on mobile

Tags: html, ios, css

i have a page that has 3 big container, all of them has an alpha transparent background 
they work fine on desktop but on tablet (iOS and android) and iphone the % sum seems incorrect

```
<div style="position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; height: 10%;"> CONTAINER 1 </div>
<div style="position: fixed; top: 10%; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 5%;"> CONTAINER 2 </div>
<div style="position: fixed; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0; height: 5%;"> CONTAINER 3 </div>
```

i also try to assign bootm and height at container 1 and 3 instead height but the 3 box works fine on desktop browser n mobile the 3 box overlap for 1/2px or they have a little 1/2px space

all 3 box has the same PNG with alpha, where overlap the color gets darker
if i can't fix % would be ok to find a solution (is is possible) only on mobile to alowe overlap without sum backgroud

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you set the meta tag

```
<meta name="viewport" width="device-width" />
```

This will set 100% to 100%

Comment: This help a lot, i guess the best is a mix viewport + GCyrillus first example. Even if is view is not perfect as on desktop. If i don't apply GCyrillus suggestion i get a tiny space, i i do a tiny overlap. That maybe is better than space. I guess no solution to avoid that transparent BG overlap multiplay.

Comment: Acttually i saw that on desktop with GCyrillus first example I can see overlap too, so i'm going bach with height

Answer (score 0):

Do your divs also have padding?

By default, the percentage width for CSS does not include the padding on most browsers. For instance, if you have a width of 25%, and a padding of 5px, the actual width of the div is 25%+5px.

the boxsizing: border-box property will cause most browsers (the notable exception being IE7) to treat the width as *inclusive* of the padding -- so a 25% width div with 5px padding will be 25%

Comment: No, matin and paddings are set to 0

Answer (score 0):

try this instead:

```
<div style="position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom:90%;"> CONTAINER 1 </div>
<div style="position: fixed; top: 10%; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 5%;"> CONTAINER 2 </div>
<div style="position: fixed; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0; top: 95%;"> CONTAINER 3 </div>
```

the prolem is that % are average to floored to the closest number of full pixel. you may have once a gap of one pixel, and once 1 pixel overlapping.

you can then try it another way:

```
<div style="position:fixed;top:0;left:0;right:0;bottom:0;padding:10% 0 5%;box-sizing:border-box;background:yellow">
    <div style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;right:0;height:10%;background:rgba(0,0,0,0.3);">5% top</div>
<div style="height:100%;background:rgba(0,0,0,0.3);"> middle </div>
<div style="position:fixed;right:0;left:0;bottom:0;height:5%;background:rgba(0,0,0,0.3);">bottom:5%</div>
</div>
```

ifyou  provided a codepen or fiddle, it would have been much easier for all of us

Answer (score 0):

it's true that it doesn't work on a mobile browser but works fine on an android  tab check

http://devilspc.in/stackoverflow/css-value.html